# Recipient view doesn't appear the fields defined in the template and only show the CLOSE Button on the page

Tags: docusignapi

We have a production integrated Docusign and it works well. We want to test some features and created a new developer account, it worked well. When we switched to an old developer account created 2 years ago, there are a issue for the recipient view.The recipient view only show the original document defined in the template without any fields, such as name, signature filed, appearing on the document, and only showed the 'FINISH' button on the top bar.  The code and template definition are same, only the accounts are different. Compared the setting between these 2 accounts, looks like they are same. Any reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One guess is that you use [AutoPlace](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/AutoPlace-New-DocuSign-Experience) or anchor tags and that the scope was set for document in one account and template in the other. That would explain this. You would have to contact [DocuSign customer support](https://support.docusign.com/) to change this setting for your other account.